# How to restart mutt to pick new configuration?

Tags: mutt

We use mutt in our prod servers to send mails. It uses sendgrid smtp url. Recently i changed sendgrid password in .muttrc file. Now i am getting following error:

```
SASL authentication failed
Could not send the message.
```

I searched over net but could not get a specific command to restart mutt. I got this 1 link which says that i need to use `:source`. But could not figure out how to actually do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may reread the configuration file with:

```
 :source ~/.muttrc
```

... assuming your configuration file is named ".muttrc" and resides in your home directory.

Comment: Beware that this sourcing .muttrc adds new settings but do not remove old. For example if you change theme in muttrc, and source it, mutt will update all changed theme elements but will keep older settings which are not defined in new theme.